# Declare a variable as a ROWTYPE - Trigger function

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger, sql-function

In this problem, I've created a table called groups(id, name, group_id INTEGER NULLABLE,class_id INTEGER NULLABLE), the logic is to classify the data between groups, classes and subclasses. A group has many classes, and a class has many subclasses. I thought to make a trigger function in plpgsql that guarantees some conditions before insert or update data.

The conditions to classify the data are below.

- Groups: 
  the user needs to insert only the **name** value. 
  **group_id** and **clazz_id** must be NULL values.
- Classes: 
  the user needs to insert only the **name** and **group_id** values. 
  **group_id** must be an INTEGER NOT NULL value and **clazz_id** is a NULL VALUE. 
  **group_id** must attend the conditions to classificate as a Group.
- Subclasses: 
  The user needs to insert only the **name**, **group_id** and **clazz_id** values. Thus, you can set the **group_id** value equals to the **group_id** who belongs to the **clazz_id** for guarantee that the condition is true. 
  **group_id** must be the same **group_id** as the **class_id** setted. 
  **clazz_id** must attend to the conditions to classificate as a Class.

.

```
CREATE FUNCTION emp_subclasse() RETURNS trigger AS $subclasse_verification$
DECLARE
  group groups%ROWTYPE;
  classe groups%ROWTYPE;
  class_group groups%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  group =(SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id=NEW.group_id);
  classe =(SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id=NEW.clazz_id);
  class_group =(SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id=classe.group_id);
  IF NEW.clazz_id IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF (classe.group_id) IS NULL THEN
          RAISE EXCEPTION 'A CLASS MUST POINT TO A GROUP';
      ELSIF classe.group_id IS NOT NULL THEN
          NEW.group_id = classe.group_id;
          IF class_group.group_id IS NOT NULL OR class_group.clazz_id IS NOT NULL THEN
              RAISE EXCEPTION 'A GROUP CANNOT HAVE A GROUP_ID OR CLASS_ID POINTED';
          END IF;
      END IF;
      IF classe.clazz_id IS NOT NULL THEN
          RAISE EXCEPTION 'CANNOT CLASSIFY A CLASS AS A SUBCLASS';
      END IF;
  ELSIF NEW.clazz_id IS NULL THEN
      IF NEW.group_id IS NOT NULL THEN
          IF group.group_id IS NOT NULL OR grupo.clazz_id IS NOT NULL THEN
              RAISE EXCEPTION 'A GROUP CANNOT HAVE A GROUP_ID OR CLASS_ID POINTED';
          END IF;
      END IF;
  END IF;
END;
$subclasse_verification$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER subclasse_verification BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON groups
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE emp_subclasse();
```

However, when I try to insert values, I get the error `[2018-11-20 16:35:20] [42601] ERROR: subquery must return only one column
[2018-11-20 16:35:20] WHERE: PL/pgSQL function emp_subclasse() line 7 at assignment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  group =(SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id=NEW.group_id);
  classe =(SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id=NEW.clazz_id);
  class_group =(SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id=classe.group_id);
```

These subqueries are returning all columns (SELECT *). To populate the variables correctly, either select the row without expanding: `group := (SELECT groups FROM groups WHERE ...)` or do a SELECT INTO: `SELECT * INTO group FROM groups WHERE ...`